# ZSH: change prompt just before command is run

Tags: zsh, prompt, hook

I would like to have a two-line prompt in `zsh`, but collapse it to a very small one just after pressing `ENTER`, so that it doesn't show up in the terminal scroll history. After typing two commands, the terminal should look like this while typing the third:

```
> echo Command 1
Command 1
> echo Command 2
Command 2
+------------ Long prompt ----------+
`> echo typing a new command here…
```

I tried getting something with the `preexec` hook and `zle reset prompt`, but I get the error `widgets can only be called when ZLE is active`:

```
$ autoload -U add-zsh-hook
$ hook_function() { OLD_PROMPT="$PROMPT"; export PROMPT="> "; zle reset-prompt; export PROMPT="$OLD_PROMPT"; }
$ PROMPT=$'+------------ Long prompt ----------+\n\`> '
+------------ Long prompt ----------+
`> add-zsh-hook preexec hook_function
+------------ Long prompt ----------+
`> echo Test
hook_function:zle: widgets can only be called when ZLE is active
Test
+------------ Long prompt ----------+
`>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the `preexec` function is called, `zle` is already finished and hence, zle widgets can't be used any more.

So, you have to intercept the pressing of the `ENTER` key before `zle` terminates. By default `ENTER` is bound to `accept-line`, but this might depend on other tricks you already use;

```
$ bindkey | grep '\^M'
"^M" accept-line
```

We now write a new widget we want to bind to `ENTER` instead:

```
del-prompt-accept-line() {
    OLD_PROMPT="$PROMPT"
    PROMPT="> "
    zle reset-prompt
    PROMPT="$OLD_PROMPT"
    zle accept-line
}
```

The logic is taken from your approach. In the last line we call the `accept-line` widget or anything else which was executed on pressing `ENTER`.

Finally we introduce the new widget to `zle` and bind it to `ENTER`:

```
zle -N del-prompt-accept-line
bindkey "^M" del-prompt-accept-line
```

Et voilà:

```
> echo foo bar
foo bar
+------------ Long prompt ----------+
`> echo this is my new command... not pressed ENTER, yet!
```

Comment: very cool. i used this and added a timestamp and path which suited my work well.

Comment: How about rewriting on these too: ctrl-c, job ends, etc.
lots of ways the prompt can come onto a newline without the user pressing enter