# zsh change RPROMPT time on enter

Tags: command-line, zsh

I have found resources on configuring zsh's right prompt (**RPROMPT**) to be the date and time and this works great.

However the time the prompt renders (after the last command) and the time that I press enter are different (sometimes much later).

It would be useful for measuring elapsed time if, upon hitting enter, the `RPROMPT` was rewritten to be the exact time I hit enter.

Searching SO and the web I didn't find anything but suspect that I may need to do this using `oh my zsh`, and/or there's a command `zle` mentioned here (closest resource I could find):

[ZSH: change prompt just before command is run](https://superuser.com/questions/1027957/zsh-change-prompt-just-before-command-is-run)

How would I do this?

Comment: Won't it then show the time once the command is complete in the next prompt? Thus you can calculate the time a command takes to run by first hitting enter on a new command, run the command then compare when it completes.

Comment: Also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26585789/1418337)